# Can't run uwsgi --myproject.ini command

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-16.04, uwsgi

Can't run uwsgi --myproject.ini.
Obtained error: ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref

I'm trying to run django project with virtualenv under uwsgi

myproject.ini

```
[uwsgi]

home            = /var/virtualenv/myproject
chdir           = /var/virtualenv/myproject/www
module          = project.wsgi
plugins         = python
master          = true
processes       = 4
no-orphans      = true
socket          = /var/virtualenv/myproject/config/project.sock
pidfile         = /var/virtualenv/myproject/config/pid
log-date        = true
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
touch-reload    = /var/virtualenv/myproject/config/touchme
```

Trace:

```
File "./project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
        from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
      File "/var/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 2, in <module>
        from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
      File "/var/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 8, in <module>
        from django import http
      File "/var/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.http.cookie import SimpleCookie, parse_cookie
      File "/var/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/http/cookie.py", line 6, in <module>
        from django.utils.encoding import force_str
      File "/var/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py", line 10, in <module>
        from django.utils.functional import Promise
      File "/var/virtualenv/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 1, in <module>
        import copy
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 52, in <module>
        import weakref
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/weakref.py", line 14, in <module>
        from _weakref import (
    ImportError: cannot import name _remove_dead_weakref
```

Comment: What is your Django and Python version?

Comment: Python 2.7.15 and Django 1.11.13

Comment: Looks like a b0rked Python installation. Try installing a separate one and using virtualenv.